# Integrate a function that takes as input a scalar value and outputs a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a function that takes as an input a scalar value, and outputs a matrix (following is an MRE with size 2x2, my actual function has problem specific matrix dimensions, like say 100x100). I'd like to integrate said function over a range.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def func(x):
    return np.array([[np.cos(x), np.sin(x)], [np.sin(x), np.cos(x)]])

quad(func, 0, np.pi)
```

This gives me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 465, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 577, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I wanted to avoid looping over each individual function, so I vectorized the integration operation, in the hopes that it would accommodate this sort of a function :

```
grid_quad = np.vectorize(quad)
grid_quad(func, 0, np.pi)
```

I still get the same error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2329, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2407, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2367, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 465, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 577, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

When I explicitly wrote out my integrand as an array of arrays, this method worked

```
efunc = [[np.cos, np.sin],[np.sin, np.cos]]
grid_quad(efunc, 0, np.pi)
```

and gave the expected output

```
(array([[4.92255263e-17, 2.00000000e+00],
       [2.00000000e+00, 4.92255263e-17]]), array([[2.21022394e-14, 2.22044605e-14],
       [2.22044605e-14, 2.21022394e-14]]))
```

which is a matrix that contains the values obtained by integrating the "function" associated with each matrix position.

In pen and paper terms, I have a matrix whose entries are functions that depend on a variable. I would like to integrate each one of these functions over an interval, and receive as output a matrix of the definite integral values.

Is there a "(num)pythonic" way to achieve this?

Comment: First off, **that isn't** "a matrix of functions"; it's a matrix of **the results of calling** functions. Those functions (`np.cos` and `np.sin`) return floating-point values, so it's just a matrix of floating-point values. At any rate, the question is not clear: **what do you think the result should be**? And **what logic should be used** to compute that result?

Comment: Sorry, I had a brain fart when writing the title. I've made changes to my question to better explain my problem, hope it helps now!

Comment: Have you tried `scipy.integrate.quad_vec`?

Comment: `vectorize` has a clear performance disclaimer.  It still iterates.  Your use doesn't change `quad` in any way.  `quad` still needs a scalar valued function, which is what your second version provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`scipy.integrate.quad_vec`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec

def func(x):
    return np.array([[np.cos(x), np.sin(x)], [np.sin(x), np.cos(x)]])

quad_vec(func, 0, np.pi)
# (array([[2.22044605e-16, 2.00000000e+00],
#         [2.00000000e+00, 2.22044605e-16]]),
#  1.3312465980656846e-13)
```

The first output is your result, the second is the error estimate.

Comment: Yes thanks, this does exactly what I wanted to accomplish!